# Base font size vs. mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, font-size

Following these articles:

[CSS font-size: em vs. px vs. pt vs. percent](http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)

[16 Pixels
For Body Copy. Anything Less Is
A Costly Mistake](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/07/16-pixels-body-copy-anything-less-costly-mistake/)

I'm about to use the base size of:

```
body {
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

and use this as the base paragraph font size, resulting - on desktops - in **16px**, unless the user changes his browser or system settings.

---

The site's layout is responsive and I'm concerned about how it's going to look on mobile devices too - including small smartphones and high-DPI displays.

If I just specify `100%`, what will this result with on mobile devices? **Can I expect the browsers to choose the optimal font size** for the given screen size and DPI?

Comment: What did you do at last?

Comment: The question remains open, I still don't know how mobile browsers behave and what's the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, most modern smartphone browsers are pretty good at setting a suitable font size if you set it to 100% - but you can never be sure.

If it was me, I would add that extra layer of protection by manually setting a font size **YOU like** for smaller screen resolutions.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    font-size:18px;
  }
}
```

Of coarse, you'll have to test it out on a mobile device to get that perfect font size you're looking for.

Adam.

Comment: By using media query and px as unit you defeat the purpose of this question

Comment: I answered the question, then concluded that it was better to manually set it yourself. Adam.